# Redshift Min Window Function over multiple dates/ IDs

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have some data that looks like this (trunced):

```
date        listing_id  inquiry_id  listed_on                    inquiry_date  days_between_list_inquiry
2021-06-08  957         16891       2021-06-08T00:00:00.000Z    2020-12-22      168
2021-06-09  957         17045       2021-06-09T00:00:00.000Z    2020-12-22      169
2021-06-09  957         16985       2021-06-09T00:00:00.000Z    2020-12-22      169
2021-03-04  1117        6869        2021-03-04T00:00:00.000Z    2021-03-01      3
2021-03-05  1117        6933        2021-03-05T00:00:00.000Z    2021-03-01      4
2021-03-08  1117        7212        2021-03-08T00:00:00.000Z    2021-03-01      7
2021-03-11  1117        7449        2021-03-11T00:00:00.000Z    2021-03-01      10
```

The table captures a daily record of each listing on the day level.

For each listing_id, I'd like to create column that captures the first_inquiry_date related to that listing. So, for listing_id 957, that would be 2020-12-22; for ID 1117, it would be 2021-03-01.

I tried:

```
min(date_trunc('day',li.created_at)) over (order by ll.id asc, date asc rows unbounded preceding) as min_inquiry_date,
```

and

```
min(date_trunc('day',li.created_at)) over (order by ll.id date rows unbounded preceding) as min_inquiry_date,
```

and a variety of other order bys but I'm not getting what I'm looking for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `partition by`:

```
min(date_trunc('day',li.created_at)) over (partition by listing_id) as min_inquiry_date
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just do this

```
select 
listing_id,
min(inquiry_date) as first_inquiry_date
from [table name]
group by 1
```